# ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, session-storage

I'm encountering an issue with sessionStorage in my React app. I'm using the "use client" pragma to ensure certain code runs only on the client side, but I'm still getting a ReferenceError.

Here's my code:

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ProgressBar } from "staysure-component-library";
import Footer from "../components/organisms/footer/Footer";
import HomePage from "../components/pages/Home/HomePage";
import Styles from "./homePage.module.css";

function Page() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);
  let hideFooter = sessionStorage.getItem("footer") === "true";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hideFooter) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("footer", "true");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-surface-neutral-option-2">
      <header>
        <ProgressBar value={10} />
      </header>
      <div>
        <HomePage />
        {hideFooter ? null : (
          <footer>
            <Footer />
          </footer>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: What is the error message in full please?

Comment: ⨯ app/page.tsx (11:19) @ sessionStorage
 ⨯ ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
    at Page (./app/page.tsx:21:22)
   9 | function Page() {
  10 |  
> 11 |   let hideFooter = sessionStorage.getItem("footer") === "true";

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question. The comments are not the right place for critical details

Answer (score 0):

error is from here:

```
let hideFooter = sessionStorage.getItem("footer") === "true";
```

client components first gets prerendered on the server to show the non-intearctive page html to the user as quick as possible. during this prerender on the server, `sessionStorage` is not defined.

```
function Page() {
  const [hideFooter, setHideFooter] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This code now runs only on the client side, avoiding the ReferenceError
    const footerHidden = sessionStorage.getItem("footer") === "true";
    setHideFooter(footerHidden);

    if (!footerHidden) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("footer", "true");
    }
  }, []);

return (
 jsx here
) 
}
```

this will get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // Check if we're in the browser environment
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const storedFooterState = sessionStorage.getItem("footer");
      if (!storedFooterState) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("footer", "true");
        setHideFooter(true);
      } else {
        setHideFooter(storedFooterState === "true");
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

this must work I had the same problem with my app running in nextjs this helped me